# CakePHP: reading current model data in component?

Tags: cakephp

Documentation on creating your own Components is piss-poor.

How does one read model data inside a Component?

Trying to do something as simple as trying to get $this->request->params['pass'][0] is making me want to kill myself. Considering Components are supposed to plug into Controllers, I'm surprised it's as difficult as it is.

Comment: you should mention the cakephp version you are using. 2.2?

Comment: RTFM! Go through tutorials i.e: [blog](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html)

Comment: Grezorgz, the tutorials and docs don't address the issue. Did you even read my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you not using the available information there is?
for instance you could look directly in the code. its open source and easy to browse via github:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php#L226

there you would find out a lot more you could ever get from any API or documention.
for instance, that using

```
public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings = array()) {
    $settings = array_merge($this->settings, (array)$settings);
    $this->Controller = $collection->getController();
    parent::__construct($collection, $settings);
}
```

and then

```
$this->Controller->...
```

anywhere in your code you can access just about anything from the current controller.
just as if you were inside this controller.

so also:

```
$this->Controller->request->params['pass'][0]
```

or just

```
$this->Controller->request->pass[0]
```

PS: there are over 6 other components to learn from, besides all those test cases to it, as well.